# Manejo de roles Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Como hago para mostrar en un select que pueda seleccionar solo un usuario si este es un usuario diferente al administrador, por que solamente 
puede enviar mensajes a varios usuarios es el que tenga perfil de administrador

esta es mi vista

```
 <select name="users[]" id="users" multiple="multiple">
                  </select>
```

¿se podria utilizar una consulta de php para validar el rol?

gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener información del usuario con la sessión o realizar alguna consulta para obtener el rol y dependiendo el rol que tenga agregas o eliminas el atributo de multiple a tu select. En este ejemplo estoy suponiendo que el rol está en la variable de sesión "rol" en tu caso no se cómo lo estás manejando:

```
<?php

  $rol = $this->session->userdata('rol');
  if ($rol == 'administrador') {
       $selMultiple = 'multiple="multiple"';
  } else {
       $selMultiple = '';
  }
?>

   <select name="users[]" id="users" <?= $selMultiple; ?> />
   </select>
```

Comment: gracias por tu aporte muy sencillo de entender .

Comment: ¿Como se puede validar ,pero directamente  por el controlador ?